# How to access token through Powershell or Postman by User ID rather than Client ID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powershell-2.0, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way either in powershell or Postman to get access of myself either through login to particular tenant. I see lot of samples around getting access token either client ID or secret. But I want to run either commands or make REST call to get access token once myself get authenticated.I tried looking into graph explorer but no luck .

Comment: Do you want to perform interactive login i.e. get prompted to enter your username/password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client id is required for AAD authorization.

If you want to get an access token including your own information, you should implement [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). It will perform interactive login as @Gaurav Mantri-AIS mentioned.

We can simply get the access token in Postman like this:

[image]

[image]

After clicking on "Request Token", it will pop up a login window. Enter your username and password. Then you will get the access token.

When we log into Graph explorer, we will see the access token here:
[image]

In fact, Microsoft has registered an Azure AD application and provided the client id in the login request URL.

In short, we have to use the client id.